# connecting map frame and base frame

Tags: ros

I have a robot that publishes distance using:

```
geometry_msgs::Twist msg;
msg.linear.x = speed;
this->cmd_vel_pub.publish(msg);
```

and also I'm subscribing to odometry:

```
odom_sub = nh.subscribe<nav_msgs::Odometry>(odom_topic_name, 1, &Agent::odomCallback, this);
```

and extracting the location of my robot using:

```
void Agent::odomCallback(const nav_msgs::OdometryConstPtr& msg){
this->location.first += msg->pose.pose.position.x;
this->location.second += msg->pose.pose.position.y;
```

}

now, the location differs from the movement on the stage, so as I see it I need to use tf, but can't seem to understand how. 
Do I need to broadcast here? or use a listener? 
I am completely at a loss, so if u could help...

thanks.

Comment: With a broadcaster you can push a coordinate frame *to* tf, vice versa with a listener you can retrieve a specific frame transformation *from* tf. Have a look [here](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials) for more details.

Comment: ok. now i have 2 robots and each is broadcasting to map frame, so listening to these broadcasts, respectively will fix the difference?  

bth, each of my robots has multiple frames - base_link, odom and such. which should I connect? the base_link?

thx

Comment: If I understand well, you know the location of your robots (assuming for example that you have a GPS sensor on the `base_link`) into a *fixed* `world_frame`, which is published to tf somehow (instant per instant). Than you know all the other stuff of each robot with reference to these `base_link` frames. Now, you "have to do nothing". Tf will do the dirty work for you (i.e. you must not phisically connect the robots): for example, by calling the [`lookupTransform`](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Overview/Transformations) method you can know whatever in the other robot local coordinates and vice versa.

Comment: ok. I think my problem is that I query my location using odometry subscriber - and that isnt using tf at all. 
If I will use lookupTransform as you suggested, I will be able to get coordinates on the map frame.

is that what you are saying?

Comment: I had assumed that you have set your odometry source to publish information (*to tf*) about the coordinate frame that it manages: have a look [here](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom).

Comment: OK, look, I guess I just didn't do anything how it suppose to be. I am publishing cmd_vel and that moves the robot on the map frame, I subscribe to laser_scan and that ensures my robot avoids obstacles. 
What I am missing is this: I want to know location and pose of the robot on the map frame. I am realy not sure now what to do: connect map and base frames using tf? listen to something? publish odemetry?  please please if you can be more specific because though I read the guides you provide I still don't know how to proceed

Comment: Uhm, wait. We can speak for ages without understanding each other if we continue this way. Please, edit the post with the result of your system tf tree: use `rosrun rqt_tf_tree rqt_tf_tree` in another terminal while your node is executing, you should see something like [this](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_tf_tree).